# Angular-JS SEO no longer working

Tags: angularjs, seo

We have a site that just went live on AWS. I'm using AngularJS in the front end to make Restful calls via Restangular to a Play framework backend.

Our service provides the ability for our clients to dynamically create pages and push up and changes/news items/etc they deem necessary. This also includes dynamic "urls" they can change on the fly within our domain (like www.ourproductname.com/thisisanexample). One of the things we allow them to change is their header item so the code is:

```
<h1 class="text-center">
    {{data.title}}
</h1>
```

When we went live a few weeks back, everything was working fine with google search. We got back things we expected in the title field. Now, a few weeks later, our searches are still in the top page of google, but it's returning:

```
{{data.title}}-Name of our product
```

I've done some significant research into this, and I have been told that "huh, that's weird...it should just work." To which I reply that it has and no longer is. I registered when we first started with google webmasters and did a fetch on the page and registered with the crawler the specific client URL's that we have so far, but it hasn't really helped.

I know that crawlers running scripts are a bit new still, so if need be I know I could do phantomJS or something like prerender.io, but to add these in for effort (including learning how to do this on our chef cookbooks for our one button deploy on AWS, or to pay a service fee otherwise) might outweigh the gain if someone else has come up with a better answer or something simple. Perhaps it's something I'm missing. If anyone has any insight that would be greatly appreciated.